# プロジェクトを始めても "manage.pyのファイルが無い" と出てしまう

Tags: python, django

PythonとDjango初学者です。自分でも理解できません。教えてもらえると助かります！

『動かして学ぶ！python Django開発入門』という本を読んで学んでいます。

プロジェクトを始めたらmanage.pyのファイルも一緒に作られると本に書いてあったのですが、manage.pyのファイルが無いと出てしまいます。改善点を教えて欲しいです！
また、的外れなことしていたらどうすれば良いか教えてほしいです！お願いします！

[image]

```
> python -m venv venv_private_diary

> cd venv_private_diary

> django-admin startproject project

> python manage.py startapp diary
python: can't open file 'manage.py': [Error 2] No such file or directory

>
```

Comment: 「プロジェクトを始めたら」の部分を具体的に説明してもらえますか。また本についても出典を明記してもらえると解決の糸口になります。「ファイルが無い」というのはどのように知りましたか？

Comment: 回答わざわざありがとうございます！！すみません。画像を追加したつもりだったのですができてませんでした。本の出店は「動かして学ぶ！python Django開発入門」です。それと、No such file or directly というのはファイルが無いということでしょうか？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
django-admin startproject project
```

した後に、

```
cd project
```

していないのでは。

> No such file or directly というのはファイルが無いということでしょうか？

そうです。